# SQL Server unpivot or cross apply to handle null values and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, unpivot, cross-apply

I have been struggling to find the right example to Normalize a very De-Normalized import of state park reservations..

I have a stage table like this:

```
TransDescription   Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4   Date5    LPlate1     LPlate2
----------------   ----------  --------    ---------   -----   ------   -------     -------
DailyEntry x3      10/10/2021  10/11/2021  10/12/2021   null   null     AB12345     null
Annual Sticker Reg  null       null        null         null   null     CD45678
Annual 2 for $55    null       null        null         null   null     XY85245     TR12345
Annual 1 for $35    null       null        null         null   null     UYH5545
```

What I need is this:

```
TransDescription    PassType     VisitDate     LicensePlate
----------------    --------     ---------     ------------
DailyEntry x3        Daily       10/10/2021    AB12345     
DailyEntry x3        Daily       10/11/2021    AB12345 
DailyEntry x3        Daily       10/12/2021    AB12345 
Annual Sticker Reg   Season      null          CD45678
Annual 2 for $55     Season      null          XY85245
Annual 2 for $55     Season      null          TR12345
Annual 1 for $35     Season      null          UYH5545
```

Some things to note.. if the dates are null the PassType is "Season" otherwise it is "Daily"
Each type can have either one or two licensePlates
There are many different Annual sticker plans, and the Daily can be up to 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of CROSS APPLY and UNPIVOT. The reason for using both is that UNPIVOT excludes null values:

```
SELECT loc.TransDescription
       , IIF(loc.IsSeasonPass = 1, 'Season','Daily') AS PassType
       , dt.VisitDate
       , loc.LicensePlate
FROM   (
          SELECT  *, IIF(Date1 IS NULL,1, 0) AS IsSeasonPass
          FROM    YourTable
       ) pvt
       UNPIVOT  
       (
          LicensePlate FOR LicenseCol IN ([LPlate1],[LPlate2])  
       ) AS loc
       CROSS APPLY (
          VALUES (Date1)
           , (Date2)
           , (Date3)
           , (Date4)
           , (Date5)
       ) dt ([VisitDate])  
WHERE loc.IsSeasonPass = 1
OR    dt.VisitDate IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY TransDescription, IsSeasonPass, VisitDate, LicensePlate
ORDER BY loc.IsSeasonPass, dt.VisitDate
```

**Results:**

> ```
> TransDescription   | PassType | VisitDate  | LicensePlate
> :----------------- | :------- | :--------- | :-----------
> DailyEntry x3      | Daily    | 2021-10-10 | AB12345     
> DailyEntry x3      | Daily    | 2021-10-11 | AB12345     
> DailyEntry x3      | Daily    | 2021-10-12 | AB12345     
> Annual 1 for $35   | Season   | null       | UYH5545     
> Annual 2 for $55   | Season   | null       | TR12345     
> Annual 2 for $55   | Season   | null       | XY85245     
> Annual Sticker Reg | Season   | null       | CD45678
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6688f5c0546901119cf1bb947b5bfb62)*